# SIPHON error in ios device compilation

Tags: iphone, pjsip

i am trying to compile the pjsip libraries for ios and run siphon code from google code. Getting the following error.
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_assert", referenced from:
      _on_call_state in call.o
      _sip_ring_stop in ring.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

My Bad. I was trying to compile for simulator and device. The CFLAGS  LDFLAGS and ARCH settings messed up. Reset the flags and tried .. Now used the correct entries and used the build script from google.code.

```
export CFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -miphoneos-version-min=4.0" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m32"
export DEVPATH=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
export ARCH="-arch armv7" // or armv7
```

libraries for armv6 and armv 7 are generated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

[SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles](https://github.com/radif/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles)

Comment: directory not found for option /SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../sim-libs!!! Can you help fixing this error